# Compartir carpeta de usuario de firefox para varios usuarios en un mismo equipo

Tags: firefox

Tengo equipos que lo usan varios usuarios diferentes. Me gustaría saber si es posible que un usuario descargase datos de una aplicación web y el otro usuario accediera a esos datos, es decir, que dos usuarios diferentes compartieran la carpeta de usuario de firefox en un mismo equipo. Ejemplo:
Un usuario entra al pc con su usuario y contraseña, trabaja en al app web, descarga los datos e informacion que necesite y apaga el pc. Seguidamente entra otro usuario al mismo pc con su usuario y contraseña diferente y al utilizar la app web los, hay datos porque utiliza los del anterior usuario. ¿Como configuro firefox para que se pueda hacer eso? 
Gracias

Comment: La pregunta es antigua, pero ya que la revivieron, se me ocurre que a lo mejor resulte [Firefox Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), descomprimirlo en un directorio visible por todos los usuarios, como `C:\Firefox`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes sincronizar datos de Firefox entre ordenadores, Android o iOS mediante **Firefox Sync**:([Más información](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/sync/)).

**Sincronice sus marcadores, historial, pestañas, contraseñas, complementos y preferencias en todos sus dispositivos.**

- Para loguearte desde Firefox, entra desde Firefox en la siguiente dirección:
  [about:preferences?entrypoint=synced-tabs#sync](http://about:preferences?entrypoint=synced-tabs#sync)
- Firefox para [Android](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/android/?utm_campaign=sync-preferences&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_source=firefox-browser): Viene con Firefox Sync por defecto también.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero no es exactamente lo que quiero. Mismo equipo, 2 usuarios diferentes y los dos accedan a los mismos datos de la carpeta de usuario de firefox

Comment: Lo que quiero es tener un solo perfil para varios usuarios, no se si es posible y si lo es como hacerlo